# Extent Report Monitoring

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Is it possible to use ExtentReport to generate the HTML Report during the tests being executed when it's used as a listener?

For example, instead of the report being generated when the tests are finished, could the report be generated after the first test, and so on? I want to use ExtentReport to monitor the progress of my tests as well and showing the results.

I've learnt it's possible when using as a logger, as you can do a flush after each tests. However is it possible while using Extent as a Listener?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Since extent report is open source. One could edit the function which formulate the structure of our final report. But since extent report uses different functionalities, just modifying an endtest would cause a cascading effect on everything. 
Or another way is to save the data before flush is called and by calling flussh everytime. One could replace the existing file over and over. 
My best bet is too leave it as it is and get other listener jars to do the work for you.